# How to select all next classes until last class and hide?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, hide, html-table

Consider the following partial table structure:

```
<tr id="TEAM00349" class="trheader darker-header" data-open="false">
    <td rowspan="6">
        <h5>
            <b>
        </h5>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="org" style="display: table-row;">
    <td>
    <td>288</td>
    <td>193</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>137</td>
    <td>71</td>
    <td>55</td>
    <td>12</td>
</tr>
<tr class="org" style="display: table-row;">
    <td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="org" style="display: table-row;">
    <td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr style="display: table-row;">
    <td rowspan="6">  A0201486: sibongile Madonda</td>
    <td>
    <td>173</td>
    <td>173</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>117</td>
    <td>58</td>
    <td>45</td>
    <td>10</td>
</tr>
<tr style="display: table-row;">
    <td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr style="display: table-row;">
    <td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

I have tried doing:

```
$("#"+obj.org_id).next("tr.org").nextUntil('tr.trheader' ).eq(-1).css({"display": "none"});
```

Where org_id is the `id` of the top row:

```
<tr id="TEAM00349" class="trheader darker-header" data-open="false">
```

Am I trying to over complicate this(I have the tendency to do this)?
What would be the best way to select all `tr` with `class='org'` until the last `org` class and hide the rows with that class?

Comment: Wouldn't just hiding the rows with the class org be enough?

Comment: So if I resume ... because it'S unclear to me atm you want to : Hide all `tr`with `.org` exept the last `.org` class? this table is create by php ? or hard-coded in the `html` file ?

Comment: @j08691 I do not want to hide all the rows with class `org`, as there might be rows with class `org` further down the table as well which I do not want to hide.

Comment: So you only want to hide the first set of consecutive rows that have the org class?

Comment: @Sebastien.Beaulieu I want to hide all the `tr` with `.org` for that organization id... data is generated by python :), then I use some template-ing to create the table

Comment: @j08691 Yes :)... That is exactly what I want to do...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$("#"+obj.org_id).next("tr.org").addBack().nextUntil(":not('tr.org')").hide()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$("#"+obj.org_id).nextUntil('tr.trheader', "org" ).css({"display": "none"});
```

Comment: yeah forgot a parameter try the eddited version